# how to pass parameter with tab?

Tags: android

I am so confused, please tell me how to pass parameters with this tab host. I want to pass parameters in first and second tab. Here's my code:

```
public class TabBarActivity_BalanceInquiry extends TabActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public static String varbalMessageType;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main2);
    setTabs() ;     
    varbalMessageType = getIntent().getExtras().getString("mno");
}


private void setTabs(){

    addTab("payments", R.drawable.tab_home, AgAppAskPinForTransaction.class);
    addTab("My Account", R.drawable.tab_home, AgAppMyAccountScreen.class);      
    addTab("Spend Analyzer", R.drawable.tab_home, AgAppPaymentScreen.class);
    addTab("Notification", R.drawable.tab_home, AgAppPaymentScreen.class);
    addTab("Help", R.drawable.tab_home, AgAppPaymentScreen.class);
}



private void addTab(String labelId, int drawableId, Class<?> c)
{
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);
    TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab" + labelId); 

    View tabIndicator =    
    LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);
    TextView title = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setText(labelId);
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    icon.setImageResource(drawableId);

    spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
    spec.setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tab 0

```
getParent().getIntent().putExtra("key", "value");
```

Tab 1

```
String value = getParent().getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
```

You can call your own tab activity  like that

```
Intent theIntent = new Intent(this, TabActivity.class); 
theIntent.putExtra("targetTab", 3);
startActivity(theIntent);
```

and to pass data or parameter you can create singleton java class and pass your data to which activity you want.

Comment: no not in between tabs i wanna pass from other activity like  myactivity1.class to  tab activity 1  how i pass like this??

Comment: but ur code is called only 1 activity what i do for other 4 activities? how i called? my source code above looping all tab text name and drawable automatically arnage so how do i set imaeg text vew for eact tab? just tell me which part of my code i modify??? and how

Comment: a bad shortcut, use static variables?